# How retrieve deeper siblings using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML structure as follows. I need to extract "Value" and "String" by matching the command attributes? How to write LINQ for this?

```
 <Root>
    <Command val="1001" type="sync">
      <Status>
        <DataList>
          <Info>
            <Value>1</Value>
            <String>Sample String 1 is set</String>
          </Info>
          <Info>
            <Value>2</Value>
            <String>Sample String 2 is set</String>
          </Info>
          <Info>
            <Value>3</Value>
            <String>Sample String 3 is set</String>
          </Info>
        </DataList>
      </Status>
    <Command>
</Root>
```

I tried something as below but exception occurred while running.

```
lst = (
    from command in xmlDoc.Descendants("Command")
        .Descendants("Status")
        .Descendants("DataList")
    select new EnumList
    {
        val = command.Element("Value").Value,
        stringVal = command.Element("String").Value,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @alex - Exception was Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
lst = (
    from command in xmlDoc.Descendants("Info")
    select new EnumList
    {
        val = command.Element("Value").Value,
        stringVal = command.Element("String").Value,
    })
    .ToList();
```

and you have error in xml sample (no close tag Command), change it to

```
    </Command>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Sorry for raising simply questions. I am learning how to do this.

Comment: How it's possible to provide condition to get for a specific command that matches the input attributes?

Comment: Thank you for the support. I managed to write it. I could add the conditions to the query and extract. The comment box can't contain the whole code. So I am not posting.